# TypeError: Cannot find function getHours in object 17

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google App Script that stopped working and throws the Error "TypeError: Cannot find function getHours in object 17.". Since we haven't made any changes in the code and I'm not too familiar with Google App Script/Javascript, I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

The code is much longer than this but I'm giving an example of an appearance of the getHours function (I can provide the full code if needed):

```
if (action.indexOf("[") == -1 && action != "") { // Check if there is some operation to take action

var roomtype = row[1]; // Reading data from the table
var desc = row[8];
var date = row[2]; 
var tstart = row[3]; 
var tstop = row[4]; 
var name = row[5]; 
var company = row[9]; 

var short_title = RoomShortcuts[0][roomtype] + " " + name + " (" + company + ")"; // Creating title of the Calendar entry
if (action == "Tentative") { short_title = "PROV: " + short_title; }              // This is for Tentative events

var year = date.getYear(); // Getting the date and time and transforming it for the calendar
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();    
var startHour = tstart.getHours();
var startMinute = tstart.getMinutes();
var stopHour = tstop.getHours();
var stopMinute = tstop.getMinutes();
var startdate = new Date(year, month, day, startHour, startMinute);
var stopdate = new Date(year, month, day, stopHour, stopMinute);

if (roomtype == "Gallery") {
  var repeat = 2;
  cal_EventCalendar[0]['Gallery'] = CalendarApp.openByName("Hub SMR");
} else {
  var repeat = 1;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you post the contents of `row`? I guess an implicit conversion to `Date` is taking place for the `date` var, but not for `tstart` and `tstop`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I was able to use getHours in one script but got the same error when trying to access the sheet from another script. Anyhow, after reading:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp

I put together the following solution:

```
function weeklyUpdater() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var schedule = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 3).getValues();

  var hours = new Date(schedule[0][2]); // parse string into date

  var hoursX = hours.getHours(); 

  Logger.log(hoursX + ":");
}
```

The key is using **new Date** whereas in my other script schedule[0][2].getHours() works!

Anyhow, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `row` is, or where it's defined. But the `4th` element is a number object, with a value of 17, not whatever object you expected it to be.

```
var tstart = row[3];
var startHour = tstart.getHours(); // Number object has no function getHours()
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in your spreadsheet, not in your script.
You can easily test that by double clicking on the cell that correspond to row[3] (most probably in column D) and see what happens : if it's a date object that shows only hours:minutes then it will give you a calendar popup like this:
[image]

If it is a 'ordinary' number or string then nothing special will happen and your script will never get any hour or minute from it since these statements need a date object as argument.

This is one of the dangers of spreadsheets that makes things look like what they are not, in this case  showing time value in hours and minutes while the object behind is is a full date value with years, seconds and milliseconds... one often forget that ;-)

So, check the most recent cell values and I'm pretty sure you'll find that someone typed a value the wrong way and that the spreadsheed failed to translate it into a date value.